# How to fetch all column from local realm database?

Tags: objective-c, realm-mobile-platform

I use the realm database in my project, Now i want fetch all column from local table, but i can't fide useful API.
  So realm whether support get all column from local table?
  If yes, how can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The columns come from your own schema definition, so usually an app developer would know the columns.

However, if the schema is unavailable, you can get it from the Realm.
In Objective-C, you can use RLMSchema which is documented here:

https://realm.io/docs/objc/3.0.2/api/Classes/RLMSchema.html

and in the links from this page.

Comment: Thanks very much，this answer is exactly what I want !!